# redis bitcount example not working

Tags: redis, bitcount, redis-server, redis-cli

I was playing with redis and tried the bitcount example: http://redis.io/commands/bitcount .

```
127.0.0.1:6379> SET mykey "foobar"
OK
127.0.0.1:6379> BITCOUNT mykey
(error) ERR unknown command 'BITCOUNT'
```

my redis version are as follows:

```
mohit@mohit:~$ redis-server --version
Redis server v=3.0.1 sha=00000000:0 malloc=jemalloc-3.6.0 bits=64 build=ecf41ef76feca5d
mohit@mohit:~$ redis-cli --version
redis-cli 3.0.1
```

I verified with the website, 3.0.1 is the latest stable version. What went wrong in this arrangement?

Comment: Interesting.  Maybe the command was renamed, or a bug?  Redis 2.8.9 handles it just fine.

Comment: @sberry I tried with redis 2.8.12 on a different system, it worked just fine. Which command has been renamed, which you are talking about?

Comment: Could you provide an `INFO` output of the instance? Btw @sberry was referring to the ability to disable commands via redis.conf directives.

Comment: Note for next users: saw this resolved in the Redis issues @ Github, the instance was actually a very old 2.4 one.

Comment: @antirez I realized using INFO that the redis_version is 2.4, and I did sudo kill of all the redis instance I was running, reinstalled the 3.0.1 using http://redis.io/download but still the INFO returns the same redis_version.

Comment: @antirez I tried again, but this time added `make install` after `make` and before `make test`, shouldn't that be added to documentation?

Comment: Check the README file "Installing Redis" section.